# Transparent background with ggplotly in R not possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

here is my theme

```
theme(
    text = element_text(size = 14, color = "white"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10, color = "white", face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y =element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x =       element_blank(),
    axis.title.y =       element_blank(),
    panel.background =   element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    plot.margin =        unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "lines"),
    legend.text =        element_text(size = 10, 
                                      color = "white",
                                      face = "bold",
                                      margin = margin(l = 0.25, unit = "cm")
                                      ),
    legend.title =       element_blank(),
    legend.background =   element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)
  )

    ggplotly(plot)
```

Everything works as expected and I can use all colors but when I set the backgrounds to transparent I get a white background as result. Does ggplotly not accept transparent backgrounds?

Comment: If you add  legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent") and 
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),

Comment: Did not work. Still white.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace transparent by

```
"#RRGGBBAA"
```

(from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html)

and did you export you plot to check the transparency ?

Comment: I get the following error message when I try this: "invalid hex digit in 'color' or 'lty'"